# How to use predicate logic to write "Product of an even number and another number is even"?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

So this is the correct solution where $U(x)$ means "odd" but personally I only did it with one of them , as in , I didn't use the or-statement to show "when either $y$ is even or $z$ is even" , and I don't see the need for that either , but I am apparently wrong.

Aren't $y$ unknown just like $z$ ? So why do we have to write it twice is the point , when it basically means the same thing?

[image]

Comment: So what was your attempt, and what were you told was a good answer?

Comment: The way I am reading the Question , **OP Answer** is "line 1" in that Image , @Bram28 , while the **Wanted Answer** seems to be "line 1 + line 2" in that Image.

Comment: The statement is "product of an even number and another number is even", not "product of an even number and an odd number is even". So you don't need to specify $U(z)$ (in the first implication) or $U(y)$ in the second. If you just delete those it's fine. I also think it's somewhat open to interpretation whether you need to write both implications. I think just the first would be ok, since multiplication is commutative. You could even write simply $\forall x \forall y \neg U(x) \implies \neg(U(x\cdot y))$.

Answer (score 3):

Your Original Solution with 1 Condition is wrong.
The given New Solution with 2 Conditions is also wrong.
I will give Some Ways to get a Correct Solution , though there is Potential for variations & tweaks.

Statement says EVEN number times "other number" is EVEN. It is not saying "other number" is ODD. It is not saying "other number" is EVEN.

Hence , we can not make the "other number" ODD ( or EVEN ) & we have to make it more general.

Your Original Solution covers the Case $EVEN \times ODD$ , while the New Solution includes the Case $ODD \times EVEN$ , though the Case $EVEN \times EVEN$ is not covered , which might require a new term , making it longer.

More-over , we have 2 "INPUT" numbers , hence , there is no need to use 3 variables.

With that thinking , try this :
$\forall x , y : \lnot U(x) \implies \lnot U(xy) \tag{1}$

In Case , we have to worry whether multiplication is commutative or not , then try this :
$\forall x , y : \lnot U(x) \lor \lnot U(y) \implies \lnot U(xy) \tag{2}$
$\forall x , y : \lnot U(x) \implies \lnot U(xy) \lor \lnot U(yx) \tag{3}$

Finally , we might want to consider the Case $ODD \times ODD$ , though that is not strictly necessary here , since it is not given in the Statement. Covering that Case is very easy :
$\forall x , y : \lnot U(x) \lor \lnot U(y) \iff \lnot U(xy) \tag{4}$

Comment: Okay now I understand why my solution is wrong, but this solution that I provided isn't technically wrong tho since we check for the cases when z is both even and odd, and the same goes for y.

Comment: Well , you are not considering the Case where **"Both are EVEN at the SAME TIME"** , which is very much necessary , @Need_MathHelp , which then makes it wrong !

Comment: Okay you're actually right. I guess my TA is wrong on this one.